# Versions and user management of precompiled .exe

Tags: java, version

I have some existing .exe programs. These were mainly implemented with Matlab. Other programs are available.

The goal now is to add a user management and a version manager without implementing it in the original source code.

Of course, it would be possible to modify the original source code, but would mean an extra effort.

For this reason, I'm considering the following:

An additional program is to be created. The .exe are inserted into the program. The new program will then start, starting with loading the users and version data from a database. If the user is authorized to start the .exe, the new program starts the original .exe.

The whole thing will be exported as .jar and compiled again as .exe. Am I right in assuming that the original .exe is then no longer available?

Comment: This question doesn't sound like it is about code. Perhaps it is a better fit on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think it's in the right forum. As soon as I have decided on a variant, I will post the code here to present a small solution for future prospects.